# How do I get the ID and the class of a div added to the DOM with .find()

Tags: jquery

The following works when I try to find a class that's been added to the DOM

```
$('#myDIV').find('div[class="myClass"]').click(function(){
   $('.myClass').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

How would I accomplish the same thing but with the ID of the div as well as the class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find elements with both criteria:

```
.find('#myId .myClass')
```

With just id:

```
.find('#myId')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but you can change the selector:

```
$("#myDIV div.myClass, #myDIV #myID").click(function () { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find('div.myClass#myId');
```

But as the **Id is unique** on the **HTML** page ...

This is sufficient..

```
$('#myId').on('click', function(){
    $('.myClass').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```